# Android VideoView controls not showing

Tags: android, video

I have a video view that I'd like to be able to play/pause, and go full screen. I can't get the video to show controls.

```
private fun showVideo() {
        isLottieVisible = false
        isImageViewVisible = false
        isVideoVisible = true
        val mediaController = MediaController(activityManager.currentActivity.window?.context!!)
        mediaController.setAnchorView(anchorView)
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView)
        //mediaController.show()
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
        videoView.keepScreenOn = true
        videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true)
        videoView.setVideoPath("https://i.imgur.com/EaEK5ZB.mp4")
        videoView.requestFocus()
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener {
            it.isLooping = true
            videoView.start()
            mediaController.show()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried running your code, every things worked as expected , yet the pause/play control bar only appears after clicking on the video, which is expected behavior.the only edit i did to your code is commenting the line `//mediaController.setAnchorView(anchorView)`

[image]

Comment: hmm... I noticed it was placing the video controls behind the actual video for some reason.

I ended up replacing the video view with an EXO player.

Comment: You definitely did the right thing by using EXO player.